Using analytic continuation for calculating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2e^{ix}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$
I have the following integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2e^{ix}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$;  the complex function $f(z)=\frac{z^2e^{iz}}{(1+z^2)^2}$ has only one pole at $\mathbb{H}=\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid Im(z)>0\}$, namely, $i$, and then:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2e^{ix}}{(1+x^2)^2}dx= 2\pi i\; res(i,\frac{z^2e^{iz}}{(1+z^2)^2})$
As $ord\Big(i\frac{z^2e^{iz}}{(1+z^2)^2}\Big)=ord(i,z^2e^{iz})-2ord(i,1+z^2)=0-2\times1=-2$
And then, we have $F(z)=(z-i)^{2}f(z)$ has an analytic continuation to $z=i$ and that $res\Big(i,\frac{z^2e^{iz}}{(1+z^2)^2}\Big)=\frac{F'(i)}{1!}$ But I can't arrive at the value of $F'(i)$. Any suggestions?

As $z^2+1=(z-i)(z+i)$, we have $$F(z)=(z-i)^2f(z)=(z-i)^2\frac{z^2e^{iz}}{(1+z^2)^2}=(z-i)^2\frac{z^2e^{iz}}{(z-i)^2(z+i)^2}=\dfrac{z^2e^{iz}}{(z+i)^2}$$
And so $$F'(z)=\dfrac{ie^{iz}z(z^2+iz+2)}{(z+i)^3}$$
Given that $i^2+i\cdot i+2=-2+2=0$, we find $F'(i)=0$, so $$\operatorname{Res}(f,i)=0\implies \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2e^{ix}}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx=0$$
